# Automatically download missing packages in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I want to use package clipboard through texstudio, but it shows the package doesn't exist on my system. I faintly remember that earlier texstudio used to automatically download required packages. Not sure how it stopped doing it. How can i configure texstudio to do the same? In case I am wrong, and texstudio doesn't have the said feature, can someone let me know how to manually download a package using texstudio. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that TeXstudio is able to download packages and if so, could you please source that? Or are you confusing *editor* and *distribution*?

Comment: Yes, that's what I remember faintly. Not sure though.

Comment: Well I do not know about past features of TeXstudio but I haven't read/heard of the possibility of the rather current version.

Comment: @henry Anyways, how do you install a new package if I have to use one. I know about MPM (miktek package manger), but the concerned package is not there for me :(. What should I do?

Comment: It's not texstudio but miktex which does the on-the-fly installation. So check the options on the general tab in miktex settings. But if the package has not been prepared for miktex (=is not shown in the package manager even after a synchronization (menu repositories)) then no automatic installation is possible.

Comment: That depends on the distribution you have. I say that if you do no have roughly 2.5 GB to spare, I'd recommend a full download of your distribution. For the technicalities to get familiar with LaTeX, please check the common introductions. :)